# F# add a list of buttons to a form control range

Tags: forms, list, button, f#, addrange

I have created the following code in F#:

```
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

let form = new Form(Text="project", TopMost=true, Width=400, Height=400)

let defaultSize = new Size(20,20)

let buttonPos text x y = new Button(Text=text, Top=x, Left=y, Size=defaultSize, BackColor=Color.Aqua)

let gameButtons = [for y in 1..9 do for x in 1..9 -> (buttonPos "X" (x*10) (y*10))]

form.Controls.AddRange (List.toArray(gameButtons))
```

I get the error: `Error 1 Type mismatch. Expecting a Control list but given a Button list. The type 'Control' does not match the type 'Button'.`

I've also tried to create gameButtons as an Array as well:

```
let gameButtons = [|for y in 1..9 do for x in 1..9 -> (buttonPos "X" (x*10) (y*10))|]
form.Controls.AddRange gameButtons
```

But that resulted in the error: `Error 1 Type mismatch. Expecting a Control [] but given a Button []    The type 'Control' does not match the type 'Button'`

If I have gameButtons as a list and write `form.Controls.AddRange [| gameButtons.Head |]` it works (but with only one button of course).

So my question is, why can't I add Controls like this? How could I add all the buttons to the range?

Comment: easiest solution: change the body of `buttonPos` to `= (new Button (...)) :> Control`- the problem is that F# has no implicit cast

Comment: @CarstenKönig, absence of implicit cast is not a problem, it's a _solution_ :- )

Comment: @FyodorSoikin well in this case it is *the* problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case is easier to use Sequences. You can use the function `Seq.cast` :

```
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

let form = new Form(Text="project", TopMost=true, Width=400, Height=400)

let defaultSize = new Size(20,20)

let buttonPos text x y = new Button(Text=text, Top=x, Left=y, Size=defaultSize, BackColor=Color.Aqua)

let gameButtons = seq{ for y in 1..9 do for x in 1..9 -> (buttonPos "X" (x*10) (y*10)) } |> Seq.cast<Control>

form.Controls.AddRange (Seq.toArray(gameButtons))
```

Comment: Type inference will work for you if, rather than doing `Seq.cast` on the 2nd last line, you change the last one to `form.Controls.AddRange(gameButtons |> Seq.cast |> Seq.toArray)`.  No need to explicitly specify the `<Control>` then.

Comment: Thanks, tried this as well as the code by Carsten König and they both worked well!